# Application always starts set to "keep above"

Tags: kubuntu, wine, kwin

I recently updated from kubuntu 18.04 to 20.04. This problem did not exist prior to the upgrade and began immediately post upgrade.

Using Wine 5.0-3 I run exactly one MS Windows program EditPad Pro v5 by JGSoft - it's a tabbed text editor.

Whenever I start this program it begins set to "keep above". I can manually untick it and it will remain unticked and behave like a normal window during the current program session. But when I exit the program and restart it, it is once again set to "keep above"

I have tried making a special rule set for it in kwin to no avail. No matter how I set up the rules, it always starts set to "keep above". So I'm thinking something is executing post kwin and overriding it.

How can I stop it from doing this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem turned out to be an obscure setting within the application itself. Evidently at some point I had fumble-fingered the keyboard while the app was in focus and changed it.